# Send different data with multiple instance of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, ejs

I want to create multiple forms with three fields each- name , id and a submit button. The values in each form are different.I am doing this with ejs(rows
is an array of objects).

```
<%for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)%>
<form action="some_url" method="post">
<a><%=rows[i].name%></a>
<a><%=rows[i].id%></a>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<%}%>
```

Now the submit button should send the text inside anchor tags to another the nodejs API.But it doesn't work.Can someone please provide solution to this or an alternative solution?

Comment: use `input` fields instead of <a> tag, because you can not send values using `<a>` you need `input` fields

Comment: On using input fields, the forms send the data.but when either of the submit buttons is pressed, data from both the forms are sent. I want the data corresponding to the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding hidden values, so the form will recognize them

```
<%for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)%>
    <form action="some_url" method="post">
    <a><%=rows[i].name%></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<%=rows[i].name%>">
    <a><%=rows[i].id%></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=rows[i].id%>">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
<%}%>
```

Comment: that works but partially.when a submit button is pressed, data from both the forms are sent. I want the data corresponding to the button.